# How to upgrade Ubuntu on a VM

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware

I have a VM with Ubuntu 14.04.2 Desktop installed on it. I'm not planning on upgrading Ubuntu yet, but I want to know if it is possible, and if so, how. I am using VMWare Workstation 12 Player.

Comment: Like you would upgrade it in a non-virtual environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a VM with Ubuntu 14.04.2 installed on it. I'm not planning on
>   upgrading Ubuntu yet, but I want to know if it is possible, and if so,
>   how. I am using VMWare Workstation 12 Player.

Yes, you can. There’s nothing magical about Ubuntu being installed on a VM as opposed to a real world machine. So just follow the standard upgrade procedure recommended by Ubuntu/Canonical.

Unclear on whether you are using Ubuntu desktop or server versions, but for the server version you would open up a terminal and just type in the following command [as explained here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html#do-release-upgrade):

```
do-release-upgrade
```

Might need to run that with `sudo`:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Follow the prompts, wait for things to complete, reboot and you are all done.

For a desktop Ubuntu upgrade, just [follow the instructions here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade).